# Computed property in other component Vue 3

Tags: vue.js

I am using a tabbed based interface to limit API calls.

Looping through the tabs and displaying the icons. Everything works but the translation.

This is because it is a computed property. How can I get the computed property to show up as the tab label?

Here is my tab component:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill nav-icons" id="tabsWithIcons" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"
                    v-for="(tabObj, tab, index) in tabs"
                    :key="index"
                    :class=" { active: currentTab === tab }"
                    @click="currentTab = tab">
                    <button class="nav-link justify-content-center" :class="[{ active: currentTab === tab }]" id="subsite-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#subsites-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="subsites-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">
                        <BootstrapIcon :icon="tabObj.tabIcon" />
                       <span>{{ tabObj.translation }}</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content my-4" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="subsites-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="subsites-tab" tabindex="0">
                  <component :is="tabs[currentTab]"></component>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   
<script setup>
    import Home from '@/views/Home'
    import Contact from '@/views/Contact'
    import AboutMe from '@/views/AboutMe'
    
    import { ref } from 'vue'

    const currentTab = ref('Home')

    const tabs = {
      Home,
      Contact,
      AboutMe,
    }
</script>
```

My About me Component:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <Subtitle :title="$t('basicnavigation.tabs.aboutme')" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            content of component
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script setup>

import Subtitle from '@/components/Titles/Subtitle.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

.. some refs..

</script>

<script>

export default {
  computed: {
    translation() {
     return this.$t('basicnavigation.tabs.aboutme')
    },
  },

  tabIcon: 'person-fill',
}
</script>
```

When I print `{{ translation }}` in the aboutme component, the translation shows up, but not in the tabs component...

Is it even possible?

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

I tried this in aboutme:

```
export default {

  computed: {

    translate() {

     return this.$t('basicnavigation.tabs.logos')

    },

  },


  tabIcon: 'images',

  translation: this.translate
}
```

another error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'translate')
at AboutMe.vue:47:21

Edit 2:

[image]

Code:

```
<script>
    import Home from '@/views/Home'
    import AboutMe from '@/views/AboutMe'
    import Contact from '@/views/Contact'
    
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          currentTab: 'Subsites',
          tabs: {
            Home,
            AboutMe,
            Contact
    
          },
        }
      },
      components: {
         Home,
            AboutMe,
            Contact
      }
    }

</script>
```

I have made a sandbox of the problem here:
[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-forest-frwzn3?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Comment: My guess is, In the AboutMe component, your translation is hardcoded while in the Tab component, it's a dynamic variable. Did you check what is inside `tabObj.translation`

Comment: It's empty, see newly attached screenshots..

Comment: I guess it is clear. The `translation` key of `tabObj` is null. You should check the `tabObj` variable.

Comment: I did and added screenshot.. translation is not there..

Comment: I tried something else in aboutme component, see edit..

Comment: Have you tried declaring the components as Vue components instead of raw objects? `export default { components: tabs }` in your tab component? I'm not quite sur why they wouldn't be mounted in the component but it's still worth a shot

Comment: I tried, still nothing (see new screenshots)

Comment: Could you try creating a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) with a minimal reproducible example? I must admit I'm kind of lost here

Comment: Yes I tried:

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-forest-frwzn3?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: I'm going to be honest here, the main reason I can't solve this is because of Vue3 new syntax. As much as I try to fix your sandbox the new syntax is an aberration to the point where even trying to understanding it has become a challenge (I tryied for 1 hour). I could give you a full solution for Vue1+2, react state or hooks or even vanillaJS but Vue3 is where I draw the line. That being said I really hope someone can help you with this problem. PS: You should put your sandbox link in your post

Comment: I know right.. Vue2 I would have solved it immediatly but Vue 3 is absolutely doing my brains in... thanks for trying anyway and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Bro, first You need to make work some functions or use route from backend to make translate work, then the template that you got with original values, type it compiltely same one but with using translated values. And use function that when u click on translate button to see on your screen translated version. This is not the best option for your site or what ever u work on but it will work. With data code and info that You gave this is maximum that we can do here.
Also there is one more option to create 2 navigation headers one original one and one with translated values and try to import both in same template but then You need to write function to call right one when You click see translated or see original one.

Comment: Translations already work, but thanks for the contribution

Comment: Yeah it works but is not placed on right place cause original values are already occupying that area. That's why i suggested to make 2 different components, not one.

Comment: I have included a sandbox, if you can fix the problem I would be grateful!